# Sufficient statistic for a logistic distribution

Tags: self-study, inference, sufficient-statistics

I'm using the statistical inference book from Casella and Berger. More specifically I'm interested in knowing how to get the sufficient statistic of a logistic distribution in the form of $$f(x|\theta)=\frac{e^{-x-\theta}}{(1+e^{-(x-\theta)})^2}, -\infty<x<\infty,-\infty<\theta<\infty $$
and the result is that the order statistics of $$X_{1}...X_{n}$$ is the sufficient statistic as well as the minimal sufficient statistic. I am completely fine being able to show that the order statistic is a minimal sufficient statistic using the ratio of $$\frac{f(x|\theta)}{f(y|\theta)}$$ However how exactly would one show that the order statistic is a sufficient statistics of $\theta$ for the logistic distribution using the factorization thm.

I should note that I manage to get to this point in the factorization thm,

$$f(x|\theta)=e^{-n\bar{x}+n\theta} \prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(1+e^{-(x_{i}-\theta)})^2}$$

Comment: The order statistics are always sufficient in general whenever $X_i$'s are i.i.d with some continuous distribution $f_{\theta}$. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144646/proof-that-n-order-statistics-are-sufficient-for-a-sample-of-size-n.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Alright I believe I understand it but just clarify one thing when the Xi's are i.i.d. with some continuous distribution does this depend on the boundaries of $$-\infty<x<\infty,-\infty<\theta<\infty$$ or on the function I have after my $$\prod$$?